# selection xtype listener unable to access multifield and multifield unable to fire the dialog.form.findfield

Tags: extjs4, aem, day-cq

I have been working on disabling the content and ignoring data that is populated in a selection field that forms part of multifield that comes with CQ5 dialog

below is the code that is not working

```
    <medicineType
         jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
        fieldLabel="medicine Type : "
        name="./medicinetype"
        blankText="medicine Type"
        type="radio"
        xtype="selection">
        <options jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
          <inactive
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            text="medicine Lead"
            value="medicinelead" />
          <active
            jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
            text="doctor Lead"
            value="doctorlead" />
        </options>
              <listeners jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" 
        selectionchanged="function(box,value){
        if(value == 'medicinelead'){
            var ans =     box.findParentByType('dialog').form.findField('./medicinedoctorset'); 
            ans.setDisabled(true);  
        ans.getEl().up('.x-form-item').setDisplayed(false);
            }
            "/>
    </medicineType>

    <medicinedoctorset
        fieldLabel="doctor cards"
        jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
        name="./medicinedoctorset"
        xtype="multifield">
        <fieldConfig
          jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
          type="select"
          options="/apps/doctor-api/components/medicineview/doctorcards.json"
          optionsRoot="doctorcards"
          optionsTextField="label"
          optionsValueField="id"
          xtype="selection" />
      </medicinedoctorset>
```

Comment: I also would like to add for sake of brevity adding a comment...The vice versa approach is not working as well where I have the multifield listen in on the options field. For an example the first to see if the  options field can be accessed is not working. function(list,component,index) {var ans =list.findParentByType('dialog').form.findField('./threadtype'); 
 if(ans.getValue() == 'contentlead'){CQ.Ext.Msg.show(
{title: 'field reached',  msg: 'You are allowed to see  items in the options',icon:CQ.Ext.MessageBox.WARNING,buttons: CQ.Ext.Msg.OK}
                 );return false;
       }
}

Comment: Not sure what exactly you are trying to do in the code, but it seems to me that you are trying to disable a particular field medicinedoctorset. Try adding id to the field you want to disable, get and disable the field as CQ.Ext.getCmp("idOfTheFieldToBeDisabled").setDisabled(true); Hope this helps.

Comment: Happy to know that it works. I have copied the comment and added it in the answer please accept answer so that it might be helpful for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what exactly you are trying to do in the code, but it seems to me that you are trying to disable a particular field medicinedoctorset. Try adding id to the field you want to disable, get and disable the field as CQ.Ext.getCmp("idOfTheFieldToBeDisabled").setDisabled(true); Hope this helps.